# UItableView getting hang when deleting a cell with fade effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am facing an unknown issue while deleting a cell in tableview with fade effect. Below is the code for delete cell

```
[self.recordArray removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

When I perform swipe operation for delete, the app is getting hang. Can any suggest what is wrong here?
I have written few lines of code having for loop in `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate. Does it leads to hang the table but as per my knowledge, 'scrollViewDidScroll' gets called on user touch. Please suggest.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the lines you are giving in themselves. You have no messages in console?, these are what can guide you in resolving this issue.
- is recordArray mutable ?
- are you only using recordArray in the other tableview delegate function ? (numberOfRowsInSection should return the new number correctly)

Answer (score 1):

```
[YourArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Instead of using "[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]" at indexpath just use the index path you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

In swift for example you can use the `editActionsForRowAt` from tableView's delegate. So you can use the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let delete: UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete", handler: {
        (rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: IndexPath) in

        self.recordArray.remove(at: indexPath.row) 
        self.recordTableView.reloadData()           
    })

    return [delete]

}
```

And that's it.